# Override WordPress [gallery] shortcode insertion with different name

Tags: wordpress

Say you created your own Gallery plugin that uses it's own shortcode  (eg:  **[my_gallery]** )

How would you go about modifying the default WordPress gallery shortcode insertion within the editor of [gallery] to [my_gallery] so that the client is not confused with having to remember the custom shortcode and accidentally making incorrect gallery insertions?

Answer (score 4):

first [remove](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_shortcode%29) the gallery shortcode , and then add your own ...

```
    remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode'); // removes the original shortcode
    add_shortcode('gallery', 'my_awesome_gallery_shortcode'); // add your own shortcode

    function my_awesome_gallery_shortcode($attr) {
    $output = 'Codex is your friend' ;
    return $output;
}
```

or as an alternative just rename your shortcode to something less confusing :-)